# GenStage: How to handle situations where producer cannot provide events?

Tags: elixir, genstage

Following scenario: A GenStage producer handles a Twitter Stream (using the [Stream API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview) and [ExTwitter](https://github.com/parroty/extwitter)) and providing a set of tweets (max. the demand the consumer is asking for) to a GenStage consumer. The consumer then just prints them.

Following problem: I am looking for specific tweets so there aren't always new tweets available. If the GenStage producer is returning an empty list of events, the consumer will stop asking. See [this issue and José Valims reply](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/issues/80) for more.

I am not sure how to address this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
defmodule MyApp.TwitterProducer do
  use GenStage
  alias MyApp.TwitterStream

  def start_link(:ok) do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    # This creates a regular Elixir Stream
    # I use this as the state so that not every
    # time the consumer asks for new data
    # a new stream is initiated
    stream = TwitterStream.get_stream
    {:producer, stream}
  end

  def handle_demand(demand, stream) do
    # Take tweets from the stream and 
    # turn them into a list. Then return 
    # them to the consumer
    chunk = Stream.take(stream, demand)
    events = Enum.to_list(chunk)
    {:noreply, events, stream}
  end


  def handle_info(_msg, state) do
    # I as getting an "wrong message" error 
    # before I implemented this function myself
    # It does nothing special to my case
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end

end

defmodule MyApp.TwitterConsumer do
  use GenStage

  def start_link() do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:consumer, :the_state_does_not_matter}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, state) do

    Process.sleep(3000)
    IO.inspect(events)

    # We are a consumer, so we would never emit items.
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end

end

# Let's fire this thing up
{:ok, p} = GenStage.start_link(MyApp.TwitterProducer, :ok, name: MyApp.TwitterProducer)
{:ok, c} = GenStage.start_link(MyApp.TwitterConsumer, :ok, name: MyApp.TwitterConsumer)
GenStage.sync_subscribe(c, to: p, max_demand: 3)
```

What happens is: This runs for a while, then stops. As I understand as soon as there is an empty event list returned by the producer.

**Edit:** Interestingly enough: If I set demand to 1 it keeps running. But it is much, much slower than querying the Twitter Stream API directly. Meaning I receive ten times less tweets. My theory is that it is due to the repeated `Stream.take` calls instead of just calling `Enum.to_list` for the whole stream. But I find it still very confusing. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: How about creating a special return list to indicate no tweets found?

Comment: Issue here is: Streams are lazy. I don't see a way of checking if there are elements present and then returning a special list. If I call Enum.count/1 for example the code waits until there actually are elements. This will lead to a timeout.

Comment: Ok then if it stops simply restart it.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I have a very strong feeling that this is not the right way. I don't want to get it to run somehow without understanding what is going on. I want to understand this behavior and solve it in the correct and intended way.

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  Restarting it is the "correct and intended way"  as far as I know.  Google for the "Erlang Way"  and the "Let It Crash"  philosophy and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Hm, I disagree. Yes, failing fast and failing safe is Elixir philosophy. But for me that doesn't translate into "well, if you don't understand why it's failing, just ignore it and restart the process". I think building something that works and keeps running is better than just restarting it. And I know there is a reason why it fails and a way to prevent it. I just have to find it.

Comment: I'm sorry--you said that you're getting an empty list returned by the producer.  That doesn't sound like an error; rather a natural consequence of not finding matching tweets.  Hence my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6):

There is a significant (but unfortunately not expressed in bold) sentence in the documentation on [`GenStage.handle_demand/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#c:handle_demand/2):

> The producer must **either store the demand or return the events requested**.

That said, instead of block on `Stream.take` one might be explicitly aware of the task might be blocking and handle the case, collecting the demand in such a case using [`Task.await/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#await/2) with a reasonable timeout (maybe [`Task.yield/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield/2) could be of use in more complicated checks, but here it seems to be an overkill.)

From the documentation:

> If you don’t want the task to fail then you must change the `heavy_fun/0` code in the same way you would achieve it if you didn’t have the async call. For example, to either return `{:ok, val} | :error` results **or, in more extreme cases, by using `try/rescue`**.

The documentation lacks the examples, though. OTOH, here it probably would be easier just to return empty list and forget about collecting demand:

```
def handle_demand(demand, stream) do
  try do
    task = Task.async(fn ->
      stream
      |> Stream.take(demand)
      |> Enum.to_list()
    end)
    Task.await(task, 1000) # one sec
  catch
    :exit, {:timeout, {Task, :await, [_, 1000]}} ->
      {:noreply, [], stream}
  else
    events when is_list(events) ->
      {:noreply, events, stream}
  end
end
```

Comment: Question, what would happen if a producer-consumer which is consuming this producer receives an empty list as events? would it also hangs?

Comment: @lapinkoira I have no idea; I think yes, but I never ran in such a situation.